# Bouncy Castle (1.72 version) Upgrade for java 11, org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: handshake_failure(40); No selectable cipher suite

Tags: upgrade, bouncycastle, java-11, handshake, tls1.3

```
org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsServerProtocol srvPro = new TlsServerProtocol(con.getInputStream(), con.getOutputStream());
```

srvPro.accept(server);

is causing

> Exception :org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: handshake_failure(40); No selectable cipher suite - [MyApp L145  MyApp.run]?

I am using `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` cipher suite.

Please suggest JAVA 11 compatible cipher suites.

I have tried two or three cipher suites

`TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`,`TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` etc.
I have even tried to handle it using sslhandshakeexception.

But nothing worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what cipher suites your server will support and override TlsServer.getSupportedCipherSuites to return that list (see DefaultTlsServer.getSupportedCipherSuites for an example).

Each cipher suite in that list should have credentials available in case it is negotiated. For example, TLS_RSA_* cipher suites need RSA encryption credentials; override AbstractTlsServer.getRSAEncryptionCredentials to return an appropriate TlsCredentialedDecryptor. Second example, TLS_*_RSA_* cipher suites need RSA signing credentials; override AbstractTlsServer.getRSASignerCredentials to return an appropriate TlsCredentialedSigner.

Finally the client has to actually offer one of the cipher suites you support. If the client is under your control, make sure to choose a cipher suite from the server-supported list. If you do not control the client, the best you can do is try to support a reasonable list of cipher suites to maximize the chances that client and server will have at least one in common.

Consider debugging the call to getSelectedCipherSuite to understand the exact reasons for the failed negotiation in your case. You could also override TlsServer.notifyOfferedCipherSuites and log the offeredCipherSuites to see what the client is actually offering. A third option is to use a tool like Wireshark to inspect the ClientHello.